# onActivityResult is called for parent activity not child

Tags: android, android-activity, tabactivity

I have tabActivity with several child Activities. From activity **A** I start camera or gallery:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Utils.getImagePath().getPath());
intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
startActivityForResult(intent, Utils.CROPPER_PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
```

and

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, Utils.CROPPER_PICK_FROM_FILE);
```

The result is returned to Activity **A**

Also I have activity **B**, that makes image cropping (I start it from activity **A**). But it's result is returned to TabActivity (on some phones it returns to activity **A**). How can I prevent it?

**EDIT**:

I start **activity B (which makes crop)** from **activity A** (not from activity, from other class )

```
final CropStarter starter = new CropStarter(mContext);
starter.startCropping(path);

public void startCropping()
{
final Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, CropImage.class);
        intent.setData(mImagePath);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Utils.getImagePath());
        intent.putExtra("outputFormat", "PNG");
        mContext.startActivityForResult(intent, Utils.CROPPER_CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

if I start activity B from A with this code:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, CropImage.class);
```

it has the same result: result is returned to **tabActivity**

Comment: What's your code to startActivityForResult from B?

Comment: Probably a problem with your mContext

Comment: mContext is defined as Activity. I use **CropStarter** in another place (start crop not from tab activity's child and it works)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So problem was that I forgot to add in the activity tag in manifest this:

`android:configChanges="bla bla bla |screenSize`

On some devices camera view fires screen size to change, so I did not handle this situation.